# How to change user credentials of windows service from command line?

Tags: command-line, windows-services

How to change user credentials of windows service from command line?

Comment: not programmer related, try serverfault.com for such a questions.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
sc.exe config "Service Name" obj= "DOMAIN\User" password= "password" type= own
```

See [Shortcut Setting Log-On Credentials for Windows Services » jonathanmalek.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20150628160340/http://jonathanmalek.com/2007/12/31/shortcut-setting-log-on-credentials-for-windows-services/).

@MattT points out that on Windows Server 2008R2 you have to add `type= own`, but prior to that version it isn't necessary.

In PowerShell 3+, you can avoid escaping the arguments with the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing): `--%`

```
sc.exe --% config "Service Name" obj= "DOMAIN\User" password= "password" type= own
```

Comment: Is there any way to grant the user the "Log on as a Service" right from the command line as well?

Comment: Apparently there's a Resource Kit tool for this: http://serverfault.com/questions/188383/looking-to-add-the-log-on-as-a-service-right-to-an-account-via-the-command-lin

Comment: Using sc to change credentials (of windows service) in remote computer ?

Comment: @Kiquenet `sc.exe \\servername config …` (the backslashes are required) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990290.aspx

Comment: Note that special characters in passwords require escaping--in my case a `%` caused a service logon failure until I changed it to `%%`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27451200/550712.

Comment: @MarkBerry Yes, depending on what command line you are using. cmd.exe requires escaping %, in powershell you should quote the strings using single quotes (escaping as appropriate), to minimize the amount of escaping required. Just using a variable for the password in powershell could also simplify the process.

Comment: I'm using a "DOS" batch (.cmd). Seems that it may be enough to enclose the password in double quotation marks, then double up `%%` and `""` in the password. Didn't actually try typing it at the command line as the OP asked--that might work differently.

Comment: as of Windows server 2008R2 it is necessary to add the argument "type= own" (without the quotes) for this to work.  Otherwise sc reports the error "The parameter is incorrect"

Comment: After changing logon from this command, I faced issue while starting the service using "net start service_name".
This happened because of logon service rights missing from user.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc794944(v=ws.10)

Answer (score 12):

I simply called WMI from powershell to do this.

```
$Svc = Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='ServiceName'"
$Svc.Change($Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, "User", "Password")
```

Don't forget to restart the service afterwards:

```
Stop-Service -Name 'ServiceName'
Start-Service -Name 'ServiceName'
```

For more fun with WMI and services, see
[Win32_Service Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418.aspx)

Comment: You have an odd definition of simple.  ;)

Comment: It's simple if you understand WMI.  Of course, WMI isn't simple. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using WMI results in non-encrypted communication between your machine and the machine you are changing the service credentials on. So your new password can be sniffed quite easily. You just have to parse the WMI blob send over the network. By now I found no really secure way to change a service accounts password remotely with a tool.

Comment: Can't you force encrypted communication? Something from this page might help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393266(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

For those who are wondering how to pass a secure password:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential -UserName 'Domain\username' -Message 'Enter password below'
$service = Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='SERVICE_NAME'"
$service.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$credentials.username,($credentials.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString))
```