# Change password on local service account

Tags: powershell

I am in dire need of some scripting help. Due to an unfortunate mistake I made when trying to deploy **PowerShell Remoting** using **GPO** in our organization,  the **WinRM** service on our client workstations (correctly) logs on using the "Network Service" local account , but unfortunately it uses a password (which should be blank by default).

Is there a script that changes the password to blank on the **(WinRM)** service?

This is what I would like to achieve on our client workstations

Service name: **WinRM**

Startup Type: **Automatic**

This account: **Network Service**

Password: **Blank** (No Password)  Unfortunately right now it is set to use a password and the service will not start up.

I would like a script that could either be run as a startup script or run as a scheduled task to wipe out the password on the **WinRM** service on my workstations. I cannot use powershell as WinRM needs to run for PSRemoting. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change user credentials of windows service from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966389/how-to-change-user-credentials-of-windows-service-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [SC.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) command to remotely reconfigure services.

An example (using an elevated command prompt if applicable) to test connectivity would be:

```
sc.exe \\SERVERNAME query dhcp
```

The rest of the options can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966389/how-to-change-user-credentials-of-windows-service-from-command-line).